# Fill in overlapping circle area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two circles that intersect and I want to make the intersecting area have a color, even when the two circles are transparent. I thought I could find some way to do this with css `mix-blend-mode` property but I have had no success with it.

Of course, I could make the circles have color and decrease their opacity, but I want them to be either white or transparent, where only the overlapped area gets background color.

I want the intersecting area to be able to change dynamically because one circle will follow the mouse.
Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/Souleste/pen/jONBQRw) for that.

I'm not sure where to start on this, if css has some technique or if it will have to be done with jquery.

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) { 

  $('.cursor').eq(0).css({
    left: e.pageX - 25,
    top: e.pageY - 20
  });

  // circles
  var c1 = $('.cursor');
  var c2 = $('.circle');
  
  // radius
  var d1 = c1.outerWidth(true)/2;
  var d2 = c2.outerWidth(true)/2;
  
  // centers of first circle
  var x1 = c1.offset().left + c1.width()/2;  
  var y1 = c1.offset().top + c1.height()/2;
  
  // centers of second circle
  var x2 = c2.offset().left + c2.width()/2;
  var y2 = c2.offset().top + c2.height()/2;
  
  var i1 = c2.find('.inter1');
  var i2 = c2.find('.inter2');
  var o = c1.find('.overlap');
  
  function calc() {
    var a = d2;
    var b = d1;
    var c = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
    var d = (b*b+c*c-a*a)/(2*c);
    var h = Math.sqrt((b*b) - (d*d));
    if (d < 0 || $.isNumeric(h)) {
      c2.css('border-color', 'red');
    } else {
      c2.css('border-color', 'black');
    }
    var x3 = (x2-x1)*d/c + (y2-y1)*h/c +  x1;
    var y3 = (y2-y1)*d/c - (x2-x1)*h/c +  y1;
    var x4 = (x2-x1)*d/c - (y2-y1)*h/c +  x1;
    var y4 = (y2-y1)*d/c + (x2-x1)*h/c +  y1;
    
    if ($.isNumeric(h)) {
      i1.show();
      i2.show();
    } else {
      i1.hide();
      i2.hide();
    }
    i1.offset({ top: y3-5, left: x3-5});
    i2.offset({ top: y4-5, left: x4-5});
  } calc();
  
  
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
}

.overlap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.cursor {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 999;
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline: 1px solid #c9d3ff;
  overflow: none;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline: 1px solid #c9d3ff;
}

.circle::after,
.cursor::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  background: #c9d3ff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.circle::before,
.cursor::before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  background: #c9d3ff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.inter {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor">
</div>

<div class="circle">
  <div class="inter1 inter"></div>
  <div class="inter2 inter"></div>
  <div>
```

Comment: this must be feasible only in svg

Comment: interesting question , i think you make use of this somehow . am going to try myself .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008991/placing-divs-around-a-circle-with-starting-and-ending-angles

Comment: also here a link could help too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066171/responsive-transparent-overlapping-css-circles-with-text-align-vertical-and-cent

Comment: You coul try using a CSS clip path: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Comment: @Haroldo_OK That looks promising, I'll look into it, thank you.

Comment: Rather than fighting competing styles... maybe identifying the points of intersection and drawing a new object over top of it could be an option. Top/Bottom point by left and right... [insert math to calculate curvature / shape]. Just an idea with sadly no adequate knowledge to provide code sample.

Comment: Yeh, I tried that but just couldn't get it right, so I'm not sure what to do. @KadeM.

Comment: I can recommend not rolling your own code and using something with boolean shape operations baked in like [paperjs](http://paperjs.org/) instead, where you define your two circles, and then just ask  for `shape = c1.union(c2)` and color that however you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you can approach this is by adding a "inner-cursor" circle inside the main circle. Based on mouse movement it will move with the main cursor given the illusion of overlap.

In this case, the background color of the intersecting circles will not matter. Also, you do not have to worry about mix-blend-mode since the inner cursor has a background color and is hidden. It is only viewed if the mouse hovers over the main circle.

See this example:

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {

  // elements
  let cursor = $('.cursor');
  let innerCursor = $('.inner-cursor');
  let c2 = $('.circle');

  let pos = {
    left: e.pageX - 25,
    top: e.pageY - 20
  };
  cursor.css(pos);

  innerCursor.css({
    left: pos.left - c2.offset().left,
    top:  pos.top - c2.offset().top
  });

  // circles


  // radius
  var d1 = cursor.outerWidth(true) / 2;
  var d2 = c2.outerWidth(true) / 2;

  // centers of first circle
  var x1 = cursor.offset().left + cursor.width() / 2;
  var y1 = cursor.offset().top + cursor.height() / 2;

  // centers of second circle
  var x2 = c2.offset().left + c2.width() / 2;
  var y2 = c2.offset().top + c2.height() / 2;

  var i1 = c2.find('.inter1');
  var i2 = c2.find('.inter2');
  var o = cursor.find('.overlap');

  function calc() {
    var a = d2;
    var b = d1;
    var c = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
    var d = (b * b + c * c - a * a) / (2 * c);
    var h = Math.sqrt((b * b) - (d * d));
    // console.log(a, b, c, d, h);
    if (d < 0 || $.isNumeric(h)) {
      c2.css('border-color', 'red');
    } else {
      c2.css('border-color', 'black');
    }
    var x3 = (x2 - x1) * d / c + (y2 - y1) * h / c + x1;
    var y3 = (y2 - y1) * d / c - (x2 - x1) * h / c + y1;
    var x4 = (x2 - x1) * d / c - (y2 - y1) * h / c + x1;
    var y4 = (y2 - y1) * d / c + (x2 - x1) * h / c + y1;

    if ($.isNumeric(h)) {
      i1.show();
      i2.show();
    } else {
      i1.hide();
      i2.hide();
    }
    i1.offset({
      top: y3 - 5,
      left: x3 - 5
    });
    i2.offset({
      top: y4 - 5,
      left: x4 - 5
    });
  }
  calc();

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
}

.clip {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip-path: ellipse(50px 50px at 50% 0%);
  position: absolute;
  left: 750px;
  top: 40px;
}

.cursor {
  left: 750px;
  top: 40px;
}

.cursor {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 999;
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline: 1px solid #c9d3ff;
  overflow: none;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
}

.circle {
  background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline: 1px solid #c9d3ff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle::after,
.cursor::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  background: #c9d3ff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.circle::before,
.cursor::before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  background: #c9d3ff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.inter {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.inner-cursor {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: green;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor">

</div>
<span class="clip"></span>

<div class="circle">
  <div class='inner-cursor'></div>
  <div class="inter1 inter"></div>
  <div class="inter2 inter"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. I was overthinking this thinking I would need to calculate the shape and curvature of the "overlap" element. Thanks! Going to leave the bounty open just so that I can see different approaches to this.

Comment: @Souleste how you will manage the small circles that are hidden by the clip-path?

Answer (score 3):

On easy idea using only CSS is to consider a `radial-gradient` as background using `background-attachement:fixed`. You apply this background to the cursor element and you make its dimension/position the same as the fixed element.

All you need to add in your code is:

```
background:radial-gradient(circle,blue 100px,transparent 100px) fixed no-repeat
```

I have also optimized the code to remove the line you draw with pseudo element to consider `linear-gradient`

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) { 

  $('.cursor').eq(0).css({
    left: e.pageX - 25,
    top: e.pageY - 20
  });

  // circles
  var c1 = $('.cursor');
  var c2 = $('.circle');
  
  // radius
  var d1 = c1.outerWidth(true)/2;
  var d2 = c2.outerWidth(true)/2;
  
  // centers of first circle
  var x1 = c1.offset().left + c1.width()/2;  
  var y1 = c1.offset().top + c1.height()/2;
  
  // centers of second circle
  var x2 = c2.offset().left + c2.width()/2;
  var y2 = c2.offset().top + c2.height()/2;
  
  var i1 = c2.find('.inter1');
  var i2 = c2.find('.inter2');
  var o = c1.find('.overlap');
  
  function calc() {
    var a = d2;
    var b = d1;
    var c = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
    var d = (b*b+c*c-a*a)/(2*c);
    var h = Math.sqrt((b*b) - (d*d));
    if (d < 0 || $.isNumeric(h)) {
      c2.css('border-color', 'red');
    } else {
      c2.css('border-color', 'black');
    }
    var x3 = (x2-x1)*d/c + (y2-y1)*h/c +  x1;
    var y3 = (y2-y1)*d/c - (x2-x1)*h/c +  y1;
    var x4 = (x2-x1)*d/c - (y2-y1)*h/c +  x1;
    var y4 = (y2-y1)*d/c + (x2-x1)*h/c +  y1;
    
    if ($.isNumeric(h)) {
      i1.show();
      i2.show();
    } else {
      i1.hide();
      i2.hide();
    }
    i1.offset({ top: y3-5, left: x3-5});
    i2.offset({ top: y4-5, left: x4-5});
  } calc();
  
  
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  margin:0;
}
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}


.cursor {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 999;
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline: 1px solid #c9d3ff;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#c9d3ff,#c9d3ff) center/100% 1px,
    linear-gradient(#c9d3ff,#c9d3ff) center/1px 100%,
    
    radial-gradient(circle,blue 100px,transparent 101px) fixed,
    yellow;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline: 1px solid #c9d3ff;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#c9d3ff,#c9d3ff) center/100% 1px,
    linear-gradient(#c9d3ff,#c9d3ff) center/1px 100%,
    #f2f2f2;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}


.inter {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor">
</div>

<div class="circle">
  <div class="inter1 inter"></div>
  <div class="inter2 inter"></div>
<div>
```

And if the circle is not in the middle you simply adjust the position.

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) { 

  $('.cursor').eq(0).css({
    left: e.pageX - 25,
    top: e.pageY - 20
  });

  // circles
  var c1 = $('.cursor');
  var c2 = $('.circle');
  
  // radius
  var d1 = c1.outerWidth(true)/2;
  var d2 = c2.outerWidth(true)/2;
  
  // centers of first circle
  var x1 = c1.offset().left + c1.width()/2;  
  var y1 = c1.offset().top + c1.height()/2;
  
  // centers of second circle
  var x2 = c2.offset().left + c2.width()/2;
  var y2 = c2.offset().top + c2.height()/2;
  
  var i1 = c2.find('.inter1');
  var i2 = c2.find('.inter2');
  var o = c1.find('.overlap');
  
  function calc() {
    var a = d2;
    var b = d1;
    var c = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
    var d = (b*b+c*c-a*a)/(2*c);
    var h = Math.sqrt((b*b) - (d*d));
    if (d < 0 || $.isNumeric(h)) {
      c2.css('border-color', 'red');
    } else {
      c2.css('border-color', 'black');
    }
    var x3 = (x2-x1)*d/c + (y2-y1)*h/c +  x1;
    var y3 = (y2-y1)*d/c - (x2-x1)*h/c +  y1;
    var x4 = (x2-x1)*d/c - (y2-y1)*h/c +  x1;
    var y4 = (y2-y1)*d/c + (x2-x1)*h/c +  y1;
    
    if ($.isNumeric(h)) {
      i1.show();
      i2.show();
    } else {
      i1.hide();
      i2.hide();
    }
    i1.offset({ top: y3-5, left: x3-5});
    i2.offset({ top: y4-5, left: x4-5});
  } calc();
  
  
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  margin:0;
}
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}



.cursor {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 999;
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline: 1px solid #c9d3ff;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#c9d3ff,#c9d3ff) center/100% 1px,
    linear-gradient(#c9d3ff,#c9d3ff) center/1px 100%,
    
    radial-gradient(circle at 20% 50%,blue 100px,transparent 101px) fixed
    yellow;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline: 1px solid #c9d3ff;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#c9d3ff,#c9d3ff) center/100% 1px,
    linear-gradient(#c9d3ff,#c9d3ff) center/1px 100%,
    #f2f2f2;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}


.inter {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor">
</div>

<div class="circle">
  <div class="inter1 inter"></div>
  <div class="inter2 inter"></div>
<div>
```

We basically use the same value of top/left to have the following:

```
radial-gradient(circle at [left] [top],blue [radius],transparent [radius]);
```

<sub>I add `1px` to transparent to avoid the jagged edge</sub>

Answer (score 2):

If you feel comfortable with HTML `<canvas>` element it's probably your best friend for this type of task, I doubt there's a CSS way to achieve what you want.

*(**If there is a CSS way, it's probably going to be lot more complicated and have much slower perfomance than doing it with canvas anyway**)*

You can take a look at the code below to be inspired ([source and live example](https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-clipping-region-tutorial/))

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body data-rsssl=1>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
        <script>
          var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
          var x = canvas.width / 2;
          var y = canvas.height / 2;
          var radius = 75;
          var offset = 50;
    
          /*
           * save() allows us to save the canvas context before
           * defining the clipping region so that we can return
           * to the default state later on
           */
          context.save();
          context.beginPath();
          context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
          context.clip();
    
          // draw blue circle inside clipping region
          context.beginPath();
          context.arc(x - offset, y - offset, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
          context.fillStyle = 'blue';
          context.fill();
    
          // draw yellow circle inside clipping region
          context.beginPath();
          context.arc(x + offset, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
          context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
          context.fill();
    
          // draw red circle inside clipping region
          context.beginPath();
          context.arc(x, y + offset, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
          context.fillStyle = 'red';
          context.fill();
    
          /*
           * restore() restores the canvas context to its original state
           * before we defined the clipping region
           */
          context.restore();
          context.beginPath();
          context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
          context.lineWidth = 10;
          context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
          context.stroke();
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Guess it's something I can look into, thing is, the circle intersection could always be changing, as what I am using it for is a draggable circle that displays the intersection points wherever the user has moved the circle to.

Comment: `clip()` is not able to handle antialiasing. For circular shapes, you should really avoid it. Prefer [compositing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) instead.